# Probability of string snapping proportional to tension, and polar co-ordinates for probability density function

Tags: probability, expectation, polar-coordinates, classical-mechanics, density-function

Picture the setup:

A particle of mass $m$ attached with a string of length $R$ spins in a vertical circle around a fixed peg with constant velocity $v>\sqrt{Rg}$ in the $x$-$z$ plane, acting under its weight $mg$. In this model, the probability that the string snaps when the string is at an angle $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ is proportional to the tension in the string, $T(\theta)$.

We know the tension is given by $T(\theta) = \frac{mv^2}{R}-mg\sin\theta$.

So the tension is greatest when the particle is at the bottom of its motion (i.e. when $\theta=3\pi/2$) and the tension is least when the particle is at the top (when $\theta=\pi/2$).

If we let the random variable $\Theta$ be the value of theta at which the string snaps, then we can work out the probability density function for $\Theta$: $$f_{\Theta}(\theta) = \frac1{2\pi}-\frac{Rg\sin\theta}{2\pi v^2}.$$

The issue arrises here: the expectation of $\Theta$ is given by
$$
\mathbb{E}(\Theta) = \int_0^{2\pi}\theta\; f_{\Theta}(\theta)\;d\theta
$$
which evaluates to $\pi+Rg/v^2$, which is not intuitively correct. It would make sense for the expectation of $\Theta$ to be $3\pi/2$, the point at which the string is most likely to snap. Furthermore, if we instead define $\theta$ by the angle with the verticle rather than the angle with the positive horizontal, and so the pdf is in terms of $\cos\theta$ instead of $\sin\theta$, we get $\mathbb{E}(\Theta)=\pi$, which does make sense in this context.

I suspect the cause of this inconsistency is that the expectation doesn't take into account that $0=2\pi$ in this context. We need to use a different formula for expectation that doesn't bias towards $2\pi$ over $0$. I reckon transforming to polar co-ordinates would make sense, but I have no idea how expectations translate into polar, and how to make the outcome independent of the choice of co-ordinate system.

Perhaps changing the factor of $\theta$ in the integral for the expectation, i.e. work out $\mathbb{E}(g(\Theta))$ for some function $g$ that deals with the moment of an angle, or something...

Any thoughts are appreciated. The endgame is to work out $\textrm{Var}(\Theta)$ and maybe other statistics about $\Theta$, but obviously I need a good structure for the pdf and stuff first.

Comment: I don't think it is physically possible to have constant speed unless the string is actually a rigid rod and the constant speed is maintained by some sort of motor

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible. If you had a ball on a string you could whizz it around in a vertical circle by just wiggling your hand in the right motion, it doesn't need to be a rigid rod to provide power to a ball. I guess it says the peg is fixed, but let's just say the particle's constant velocity is a given. It's a classic A-level Physics question to derive T=mv^2/R – mg sin θ.

Comment: My thoughts on this. You already have a function that describes the tension in the string, the angle theta factor representing probability cycles from 0 to 2pi and up. Surely this needs to be sin theta so it cycles from 0 to 1 to 0 etc. This part then correctly represents the cycle of probability. Then again, you already have this in the equation where the tension is a one to one ratio with probability. Leave the theta out altogether. I don't see how changing coordinate systems will change anything. Geometry isn't dependent on the system used to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value is a summation of all the positions it could break times the probability of it breaking at that particular position. The definite integral does this summation and the result is an average angle. It should be biased towards the angle of maximum tension but it is an entirely different metric to the angle of maximum tension. The expected value of a series of bets isn't the value of the most likely win.

Comment: Yeah I appreciate this. The question is how can we engineer a co-ordinate system in such a way that means the expectation of theta doesn't depend on where we choose 0 to be. As I said in the question, taking theta=0 at the point (R,0) vs at the point (0,R) shouldn't affect the outcome of the experiment, and hence the expectation ought not to change.

Comment: Conceptually, you have a sine wave that describes the fluctuation in tension and hence the probability of the string snapping. I don't see how the integration should be any different for one full rotation no matter where you start. My thought is there must be an error in the transfer of the starting point. I don't see how the $\frac{Rg}{v^2}$ term would disappear.

Comment: I see the problem on the plot of both graphs. The theta term in front of the function in the integral means the function continues to grow despite the cycle. Hence a phase shift will come up with a different value. This doesn't look right, I would expect to see a repeating function with a period of 2 pi.

Comment: Yes precisely. In other words I reckon $\mathbb{E}(\theta)$ is not what we're looking for, but instead $\mathbb{E}(g(\theta))$ for some $2\pi$-periodic function $g$. The question is what function makes sense? Is it just $\theta$ mod $2\pi$? This wouldn't make any difference to the integral though would it... hence why I'm thinking a polar integral is necessary.

We know the expectation is the first moment of the function, or the centre of mass. Is there a formula for the centre of mass of a region in polar coordinates?

Comment: My thoughts on this. You already have a function that describes the tension in the string, the angle theta factor representing probability cycles from 0 to 2pi and up. Surely this needs to be sin theta so it cycles from 0 to 1 to 0 etc. This part then correctly represents the cycle of probability. Then again, you already have this in the equation where the tension is a one to one ratio with probability. Leave the theta out altogether. I don't see how changing coordinate systems will change anything. Geometry isn't dependent on the system used to describe it.

Comment: From an engineering real world aspect, the probability of it breaking is 1, only when the velocity is high enough so the tension reaches the breaking strength. Is this a practical consideration or is this just an academic exercise. You could assume a constant velocity where the maximum tension is 1/2 of the breaking strength, and set the probability of it breaking at 1/2 at that point. The probability cycle would then be a 1/2sin theta component. My 2 cents fwiw.

Comment: Yeah I guess it's a completely inaccurate model designed for the sake of making an interesting exercise. Maybe this is a special "quantum string" that breaks not according to the normal laws of string breaking...

Comment: Ok, a quantum entangled string that is. Good game.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I've solved my own question here. We have the tension $T(\theta)$ is given by
$$
T(\theta) = \frac{mv^2}{R} - mg\sin\theta.
$$
Then to find the pdf, we normalise $T$ by dividing by the total "mass" of $T$, the $\textbf{polar}$ integral from $0$ to $2\pi$:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{T(\theta)} r\; \mathrm{d}r \; \mathrm{d}\theta
$$
I.e. we needed to use polar co-ordinates from the very start, since the random variable $\Theta$ is inherently an angle. We can simplify this integral by writing $T$ in the form $T(\theta)=a+b\sin\theta$, where, in this case, $a=mv^2/R$ and $b=-mg$.

This gives the total "mass", $k$, of $T$ as
\begin{align*}
k=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{T(\theta)} r\; \mathrm{d}r \; \mathrm{d}\theta &= \frac12 \int_0^{2\pi} (a+b\sin\theta)^2 \;\mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac\pi2 (2a^2+b^2) \\
&= \frac\pi2\left( 2\frac{m^2v^4}{R^2} + m^2g^2 \right) \\
&=\frac{\pi m^2}{2R^2}(2v^4 +R^2g^2)
\end{align*}
So it makes sense to use
$$
f_{\Theta}(\theta) = \frac{1}{2k}\; [T(\theta)]^2,
$$
as the p.d.f. for $\Theta$, which actually ends up being rather redundant.

Now, we calculate the "centre of mass" of $T$ by finding the cartesian coordinates, $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, for the centre of mass, $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ by finding the moments:

\begin{align*}
\bar{x} &= \frac1k \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{T(\theta)} xr\; \mathrm{d}r \; \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac1k \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{T(\theta)} r^2 \cos\theta\; \mathrm{d}r \; \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac1k \int_0^{2\pi} \frac13 (a+b\sin\theta)^3 \cos\theta \; \mathrm{d}\theta = 0
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\bar{y} &= \frac1k \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{T(\theta)} yr\; \mathrm{d}r \; \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac1k \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{T(\theta)} r^2 \sin\theta\; \mathrm{d}r \; \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac1k \int_0^{2\pi} \frac13 (a+b\sin\theta)^3 \sin\theta \; \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac1{4k}\pi b(4a^2+b^2) \\
&= \frac{b(4a^2+b^2)}{2(2a^2+b^2)} = \frac{-mg(4v^4+R^2g^2)}{2(2v^4+R^2g^2)}
\end{align*}

Since $\bar{x} = 0$ and $\bar{y} < 0$, we get that (excuse sloppiness) $\bar{\theta} = \textrm{"arctan"}\left(\frac{\bar{y}}{\bar{x}}\right) = \frac{3\pi}2 = \mathbb{E}(\Theta)$, as we had anticipated.

We also obtain $\bar{r} = |\bar{y}|$. Does this equal  $\mathbb{E}(T(\Theta))$? It seems plausible since the dimensional analysis works this value out to be a force.

This is a clunky solution and I don't particularly like moving back to cartesian to get back to polar, but at least it's a solution. It's also interesting that in this case, the expected value of $\Theta$ is not an integral with $f_\Theta$ but instead with $T$.

This would also be the case for the variance of $\Theta$, where we might compute
$$
\left( \frac1k \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{T(\theta)} x^2 r \;\mathrm{d}r \; \mathrm{d}\theta, \frac1k \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{T(\theta)} y^2 r \;\mathrm{d}r \; \mathrm{d}\theta \right)
$$
to find the second moments, and then this could give us $\mathbb{E}(\Theta^2)$. Who knows... food for thought.